# Error object reference not set to an instance of an object while using Infragistics xamgrid control

Tags: silverlight, grid, infragistics, silverlight-5.0

I am using a ig:xamGrid in my silverlight 5 application. When i click on Header of grid sometimes it showing error

> Unhandled error in silverlight application object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   (infragestics.controls.grid.primitives.Headercellcontrol.GetcellcontrolFromPoint,Type)

Thank you.

Comment: Which code behind events are wired to your grid? Somewhere your code use an uninitialized object.

Comment: Have you tested with the latest service release?  There were checks for null added to the GetCellControlFromPoint method early this year.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ,uninstall ver 4 and 5 and the install Silverlight_Developer from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039 ,hopefully it will solve your problem